# How do I pass an authorization header when iframe redirects?

Tags: http-headers, authorization, ionic4

I'm working on a mobile app written in Ionic 4. As a part of it, I am communicating with an API and an authorization header (Bearer ). As a response, I get an HTML page (or an error message if an error occurs) and present it in an iframe using srcdoc. When you click on a button on that page, it should redirect you to the page but instead, I am being redirected to the login page. I was told by the developers of this website that I have to pass the authentication header each time I make a request to the server or moving between pages.

My question is how can I pass this header when a button is clicked in the iframe or being redirected?

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Angular [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http#sending-data-to-the-server):

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
  })
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don’t do a request via angular. I have an iframe with html content and when I click on a button it redirects to a domain.